# How to submit same name elements in mvc4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have multiple elements of same name.

one is before dynamic element created and second after created dynamically.

Before dynamically created element-

```
<input id="txtamt" name="Amount[]" type="text" ></td>
```

After dynamic-

```
<input id="txtamt_' + numtd + '" name="Amount[]" type="text" ></td>
```

Note-

I have same name of these elements. Now I wanted to post it through jQuery.

How Do I get value of both `input` tags. Where value will be different.

Comment: Serialize your form and It will submit an array of AMOUNT

Answer (score 0):

to get value of all input with same name you can select input with name='Amount[]' and process each input like below

```
$('input[name="Amount[]"]').each(function(){
   var idOfInput = $(this).attr('id');
   var valueOfInput = $(this).val();

   //append these values to your jQuery post with id, value pair and process it 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('input[name*="Amount"]')` jquery selector to get all of your input elements with the same name. You can then use `$.val()` function of jquery to get the values like

```
var arrEle=$('input[name*="Amount"]');
var arrValue=[];
for(var i=0; i<arrEle.length; i++)
{
arrValue[i]=$(arrEle[i]).val();
}
```

Now, the element arrValue will have all the elements of your input.